# Replacement for element.setCapture in Chrome?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

I need to capture mouse events after a `mousedown` event happens on an *element*.

On [MDN setCapture](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/setCapture), I don't see any mention about `setCapture()` not being implement
in Chrome, but trying to run [the example](https://developer.mozilla.org/samples/domref/mousecapture.html) provided produces an `Uncaugt TypeError` because `e.target.setCapture` is basically `undefined` in Chrome.

```
function init() {
  var btn = document.getElementById("myButton");
  btn.addEventListener("mousedown", mouseDown, false);
  btn.addEventListener("mouseup", mouseUp, false);
}

function mouseDown(e) {
  e.target.setCapture();
  e.target.addEventListener("mousemove", mouseMoved, false);
}

function mouseUp(e) {
  e.target.removeEventListener("mousemove", mouseMoved, false);
}

function mouseMoved(e) {
  var output = document.getElementById("output");
  output.innerHTML = "Position: " + e.clientX + ", " + e.clientY;
}
```

What is the equivalent API in Chrome?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30231880/setcapture-and-releasecapture-in-chrome

Comment: `setCapture` is an invention of IE. Don't use propietary methods when having standard methods. http://help.dottoro.com/ljrtxexf.php

Comment: I was fooled by the fact that it is documented on Mozilla Developer Network without any indication of it being browser specific. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/setCapture

Answer (score 9):

I've finally come up with a complete ES2015 solution (explained [on my blog](http://code.fitness/post/2016/06/capture-mouse-events.html)) which captures
the mouse events and effectively disables parasitic hover and pointer cursor
changes while the mouse button is pressed.

Call `captureMouseEvents(e)` from the event handler attached to the `mousedown` event:

```
const EventListenerMode = {capture: true};

function preventGlobalMouseEvents () {
  document.body.style['pointer-events'] = 'none';
}

function restoreGlobalMouseEvents () {
  document.body.style['pointer-events'] = 'auto';
}

function mousemoveListener (e) {
  e.stopPropagation ();
  // do whatever is needed while the user is moving the cursor around
}

function mouseupListener (e) {
  restoreGlobalMouseEvents ();
  document.removeEventListener ('mouseup',   mouseupListener,   EventListenerMode);
  document.removeEventListener ('mousemove', mousemoveListener, EventListenerMode);
  e.stopPropagation ();
}

function captureMouseEvents (e) {
  preventGlobalMouseEvents ();
  document.addEventListener ('mouseup',   mouseupListener,   EventListenerMode);
  document.addEventListener ('mousemove', mousemoveListener, EventListenerMode);
  e.preventDefault ();
  e.stopPropagation ();
}
```

Notice that the `pointer-events: none` style prevents any component
receiving mouse events.

Comment: It looks like setting document.body.style['pointer-events'] = 'none' makes setting document.body.style.cursor="whatever" ignored.

Comment: @MarcK. to solve this problem I've added a <div> wrapper right after the <body> and use the div to disable pointer events. Angular + Typescript  [plunker sample](https://plnkr.co/edit/CphOwUo9qbFziU0cmdGk).

Comment: or you can add cursor to the html via document.documentElement and set pointer-events to the body as suggested

Answer (score 1):

See the [issue](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=246536) here, mentioning the fact that `setCapture` is not supported. There is a suggested workaround towards the bottom of the thread, which may be of use to you.

Comment: So basically, there is no replacement for this API and we have to stick with the solution presented in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30231880/setcapture-and-releasecapture-in-chrome.

Answer (score 0):

To solve a cursor issue from the @Pierre Arnaud 's answer, set a cursor on `html` tag:

```
// on mouse down:
document.documentElement.style.cursor = "...";
```

and restore it after:

```
// on mouse up:
document.documentElement.style.cursor = "default";
```