# Issue with Drag and Drop API or?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, draggable

I'm encountering an issue with the HTML5 Drag and Drop API.

Long story short, there are three events other than `dragstart`, `dragover`, and `drop`, which are critical to my objective. Those three events are `mousedown`, `mouseup`, and `mouseleave`.

## onmousedown

When the user triggers a `mousedown` event on a given element, the following function applies attributes and listeners to itself and the target element.

```
function doThis() {
  d.setAttribute('draggable', true)
  d.addEventListener('dragstart', dragStart)
  t.style.background = 'black'
  t.addEventListener('dragover', dragOver)
  t.addEventListener('drop', drop)
}
```

## onmouseup & mouseleave

When the user triggers a `mouseup` or `mouseleave` event, those attributes and listeners are removed.

```
function thenThis(){
  d.setAttribute('draggable', false)
  d.removeEventListener('dragstart', dragStart)
  t.style.background = 'none'
  t.removeEventListener('dragover', dragOver)
  t.removeEventListener('drop', drop)
}
```

I've had to add the `mouseleave` listener since the `mouseup` event must occur over the element to which it is binded for it to be triggered. Without applying the `mouseleave` event, the user is able to trigger the `mousedown` event while avoiding the `mouseup` event altogether (due to the browser's native detection of the `dblclick` event) by double clicking the element and then sliding the cursor off of the element while not letting go of the mouse button until it is beyond the element's perimeter.

## The issue...

If the user clicks the draggable element too close to its edge, the element becomes undraggable despite the `mousedown` event being triggered.

[Here is an codepen MVC which can also be viewed below.](https://codepen.io/tOkyO1/pen/LLremr)

Why does this occur? The `mousedown` even is triggered, but the element is still undraggable...

**Does anybody know how I can fix this or prevent it from happening in the first place?**

```js
var d = document.getElementById('draggable')
var t = document.getElementById('target')

d.addEventListener('mousedown', doThis)
d.addEventListener('mouseup', thenThis)
d.addEventListener('mouseleave', thenThis)
d.addEventListener('mouseleave', alertLeave)

function doThis(){
  d.setAttribute('draggable', true)
  d.addEventListener('dragstart', dragStart)
  t.style.background = 'black'
  t.addEventListener('dragover', dragOver)
  t.addEventListener('drop', drop)
}

function thenThis(){
  d.setAttribute('draggable', false)
  d.removeEventListener('dragstart', dragStart)
  t.style.background = 'none'
  t.removeEventListener('dragover', dragOver)
  t.removeEventListener('drop', drop)
}

function dragStart(e){
  e.dataTransfer.setData('text/plain', e.target.id);
  e.dataTransfer.effectAllowed = 'move';
}

function dragOver(e){
  e.preventDefault();
}

function drop(e){
  var data = e.dataTransfer.getData('text/plain');
  e.preventDefault();
  e.target.parentElement.appendChild(document.getElementById(data));
}

function alertLeave(){
  //alert('mouseleave')
}
```

```css
body {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
}

div {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
}

#draggable {
  background: purple;
}

#target {
  border: solid 3px black;
}
```

```html
<div id="draggable"></div>
<div id="target"></div>
```

Comment: see MDN's HTML [Drag and Drop API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTML_Drag_and_Drop_API) it's full of great examples and details. You can just about copy& paste into your project.

Comment: @RonRoyston yeah, i'm already aware of all of the events, though i'm sure i still could learn something, but so little time in the day and too lazy lol

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem, when you try to grab the left element close to its right edge, is that `mouseleave` is triggered as soon as you move the mouse to the right, before `dragstart` has a chance to be triggered. You can see the events in this code snippet:

```js
var d = document.getElementById('draggable')
var t = document.getElementById('target')

d.addEventListener('mousedown', doThis)
d.addEventListener('mouseleave', thenThis)

function doThis(){
  console.log('mousedown');
  d.setAttribute('draggable', true);
  d.addEventListener('dragstart', dragStart);
  t.style.background = 'black';
  t.addEventListener('dragover', dragOver);
  t.addEventListener('drop', drop);
}

function thenThis(){
  console.log('mouseleave');
  d.setAttribute('draggable', false);
  d.removeEventListener('dragstart', dragStart);
  t.style.background = 'none';
  t.removeEventListener('dragover', dragOver);
  t.removeEventListener('drop', drop);
}

function dragStart(e){
  console.log('dragstart');
  e.dataTransfer.setData('text/plain', e.target.id);
  e.dataTransfer.effectAllowed = 'move';
}

function dragOver(e){
  e.preventDefault();
}

function drop(e){
  var data = e.dataTransfer.getData('text/plain');
  e.preventDefault();
  e.target.parentElement.appendChild(document.getElementById(data));
}
```

```css
body {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
}

.square {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
}

#draggable {
  background: purple;
}

#target {
  border: solid 3px black;
}
```

```html
<div id="draggable" class="square"></div>
<div id="target" class="square"></div>
```

To avoid that situation, you can [capture the mouse](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32868888/1009922) instead of processing `mouseleave`. Once the dragging operation begins, you can release the mouse capture and rely on the `dragend` event. The draggable element properties will be reset when the mouse is released by the user (if the element was not dragged) or when the drag operation ends.

```js
var d = document.getElementById('draggable')
var t = document.getElementById('target')
var releaseCapture = null;

d.addEventListener('mousedown', mouseDown);
d.addEventListener('dragend', resetDraggableElement);

function mouseDown() {
  releaseCapture = captureMouse(resetDraggableElement);
  d.setAttribute('draggable', true);
  d.addEventListener('dragstart', dragStart);
  t.style.background = 'black';
  t.addEventListener('dragover', dragOver);
  t.addEventListener('drop', drop);
}

function resetDraggableElement() {
  d.setAttribute('draggable', false);
  d.removeEventListener('dragstart', dragStart);
  t.style.background = 'none';
  t.removeEventListener('dragover', dragOver);
  t.removeEventListener('drop', drop);
}

function dragStart(e) {
  if (releaseCapture) {
    releaseCapture();
    releaseCapture = null;
  }
  e.dataTransfer.setData('text/plain', e.target.id);
  e.dataTransfer.effectAllowed = 'move';
}

function dragOver(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
}

function drop(e) {
  var data = e.dataTransfer.getData('text/plain');
  e.preventDefault();
  e.target.parentElement.appendChild(document.getElementById(data));
}

function captureMouse(mouseUpHandler) {
  var releaseCapture = function() {
    document.removeEventListener("mouseup", lostCaptureHandler, false);
  }
  var lostCaptureHandler = function() {
    releaseCapture();
    if (mouseUpHandler) {
      mouseUpHandler();
    }
  };
  document.addEventListener("mouseup", lostCaptureHandler, false);
  return releaseCapture;
}
```

```css
body {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
}

.square {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
}

#draggable {
  background: purple;
}

#target {
  border: solid 3px black;
}
```

```html
<div id="draggable" class="square"></div>
<div id="target" class="square"></div>
```

Comment: The issue with your solution is that it can still be glitched out via the `dblclick` event. Try clicking twice in quick succession (or double-clicking) the purple square and, instead of letting go of the mouse button after the 2nd click, continue holding it down and then slide your cursor off the purple square before letting go. The target remains black until the element is dragged once again. I had this same issue with only using `mousedown` and `mouseup` which is why i also started using `mouseleave`

Comment: I modified the first solution, to make the target black only when dragging starts. I don't know if that can work for you.

Comment: it needs to happen when the user mouse downs. your example still has issues nonetheless, since if you now click the purple box the target will stay black. i need this for a project that i'm building, which is a browser based backgammon game. when the user selects a checker, any valid target points will light up, etc

Comment: You can check my new suggestion.

Comment: I believe that will work. <33 please add the reference if you manage to find it. there's a chance i might have some questions in the future when i need to implement it again

Comment: I added a link to the original post (which points to another article) for the mouse capture.

Comment: I'm looking at the [MDN document](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/setCapture) right now, what does it mean that it "retargets all mouse events to this element"??

Comment: Usually, when a mouse event occurs (mousemove, mousedown, etc.), the element under the mouse receives the event. But when an element has "captured" the mouse, all the mouse events are sent to that element, even when the mouse is not over that element.

Comment: ahhhhh, so you would basically be able to use a `setCapture` and `mouseup` event in such a way that the `mouseup` event will trigger even if the cursor has been moved outside or off of an element? <3

Comment: Exactly. You could do the test: capture the mouse with a button, and then click anywhere on the page. The button should respond.

Comment: i was messing around with it in jsfiddle, but it didn't seem to be working that way and i had troubles understanding how exactly it was behaving. i'll try again. i've created [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45070624/obscure-method-element-setcapture), if you'd like to leave this info there too.

Comment: According to my tests, the mouse capture works only in Firefox. In order to simulate it in other browsers, we must assign an event handler to the document object. You can see an example in [this jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ConnorsFan/2Lu7swtu/4/). By default, moving over the orange div displays the coordinates of the cursor. If you click the green div and keep the mouse button down, the orange div reacts as if the mouse was moving over it. I will have to check why the answer of the present post works for Chrome (but that will not be tonight).

Comment: Oh yeah, it works for your problem here because capturing the mouse (or simulating the capture) allows us to get rid of `mouseleave`, and only react when the mouse button is released. For that kind of usage, the present code works in all browsers because the `mouseup` event is handled by the document object for browsers other than Firefox.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/149170/discussion-between-anthony-and-connorsfan).

Comment: [other SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45091825/dragstart-not-called-in-chrome). i think i'm just gonna have to write my own script for D&D, unfortunately :/