# Element.setCapture()

Tags: javascript, jquery, mouseevent, mouselistener

The [MDN documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/setCapture) is quite scant. Cannot find much else about `setCapture` elsewhere. Can somebody please provide a general explanation of the method and also explain what it means by 'retargeting all mouse events to the given element'?

Comment: @JaromandaX example isn't working...

Comment: @JaromandaX of course... did you bother to try the example yourself?

Comment: @JaromandaX obvs to write the position of the cursor but not a single event fires, so i'm not sure how that would constitute a "working" example

Comment: @JaromandaX ... It's broken in Chrome too

Comment: @JaromandaX again, as my question states, not much else about this method can be found elsewhere... it would be cool if you responded to the actual question instead

Comment: I thought perhaps you had a use for this broken obscure function

Comment: @JaromandaX i do. i'm not sure where you're going with this, but you're clearly wasting my time and perhaps your own

Comment: If you feel your time is wasted then I apologise. Does [this documentation of legacy events](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms536742(v=vs.85).aspx) help?

Comment: @JaromandaX that's worth ssomething

Comment: Thing is, even MicroSoft call it "legacy". Firefox "tried" to implement it, Chrome has not ... so you're trying to use an old method that is only implemented in (old) internet explorer and may or may not be implemented in Firefox - seems like a waste of time

Comment: @JaromandaX if thats the case i just dont understand why its still on mdn. i got a [workaround](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44939529/issue-with-drag-and-drop-api-or/45001053?noredirect=1#comment77114091_45001053) anyways, which is based on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30231880/setcapture-and-releasecapture-in-chrome).